# could not load file or assembly Error after Upgrade .Net Version

Tags: c#, .net, excel

After up great my **.net 1.1** app to **.Net 4.5** i get this error at run time

***could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies***

its happen when i  convert my data grid to Excel File;
**this not happen in .Net 1.1 version.
i Tested New version of Office but nothing changed.
**i punted Embed Introp Type = False problem is not there
Dll is copy to local too****

Whats my Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is different between last version and new 
i need to improve version of this  and change my import and remove old version Dll

```
using Excel
var ExcelApp = New Excel.Application()
```

to

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
var ExcelApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try installing the VSTO - Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office.

After that, please try adding the reference to one more dll class `Office.dll` which contains the namespace `Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core`. The DLL can be found in this default location (here I've given the path for Microsoft Office 2010). Check the PIA folder for the other version's of office.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Office.dll
```

Don't forget to copy this dll and place it in the same directory along with the .exe file and Excel `nterop dll`.

Comment: problem was in the version of my dll and i didn't remove the old one and didn't change name space and the path of object thank you for your help

Comment: @ShahroozAnsari Sure, Happy to help.